# How to fix this redirect loop?

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, asp.net, database

Backstory: Thrown into a project with C#, JavaScript and SQL - I've got little experience with either. Got a "working" website and playing around with the code (local copy of both the database and code on my computer for testing). Had the problem for a long time that every time I ran the program locally it would go to the "real" website instead of my local copy. Found out that there was a redirect and when I tried to fix it by adding an object to the database it didn't change anything - still redirected. So I changed the redirect to localhost:50000 infront of the address instead and got the error of an endless loop when I tried to change it. So I'm gonna assume there's a problem with the database or the connection to it. Here's the code where the redirect happens, but I have no idea how to fix it.

// Lots of code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        DBConnection.Open();

        DBAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, DBConnection);
        DBAdapter.Fill(dt1);

        DBAdapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query2, DBConnection);
        DBAdapter2.Fill(dt2);

        DBAdapter3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query3, DBConnection);
        DBAdapter3.Fill(dt3);

        DBAdapter4 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query4, DBConnection);
        DBAdapter4.Fill(dt4);

        DBAdapter5 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query5, DBConnection);
        DBAdapter5.Fill(dt5);

        ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt3);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt4);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt5);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        DBConnection.Close();
    }
```

// Lots of code.

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
        // Lots of code
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.websitename.com");
        }

        if (ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[3].Rows)
            {
                UsersAsDealers.Add(row["Username"].ToString());
            }
        }

        if (ds.Tables[4].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[4].Rows)
            {
                UsersAsSellers.Add(row["username"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.websitename.com);
    }
}
```

Oh and it's the last redirect that's the problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same page where all this code is running?  If so, then don't do that, redirect to an error page or some other page.

Comment: Are your sure you were connecting to port 50000?  unless you specify a port, it is randomly assigned each time you run the site from VS.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection to the database failed, you should see the error description in your VS output window (see the line **Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);**)

If you add a breakpoint in the line **if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)** and inspect it, maybe you cloud get more information about the Ds object status.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a endless loop after you enter

> localhost:50000

then I assume this code in on page_load event of your home page ? that means its redirecting to the same page again and again since the condition

> ds.Tables.Count > 0

is not met, try executing the queries in your db to see if you have valid data coming out of it.